# Two websites nginx + redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have the following nginx config:

```
server
{
  listen 80;
  server_name server1.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.server1.com permanent;
}

server
{
  listen 80;
  server_name server2.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.server2.com permanent;
}

server
{
  listen 80;
  root /home/server1/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name www.server1.com;

  ...
}

server
{
  listen 80;
  root /home/server2/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name www.server2.com;

  ...
}
```

My problem is that, when I type server2.com in the browser, I get redirected to www.server1.com! Everything else works correctly. Any idea why?

Thanks in advace!

Comment: Have tou checked with something else like curl? Probably your browser cached wrong redirect

Comment: Ouch; now I feel stupid. You're right.